# Batch file shows batch commands

Tags: batch-file, text, command, show

I got a batchfile with a length of 4776 lines. Now i want the batchfile to show the commands and text from the batchfile itself I've written.
Anticipated thanks
VVW

Comment: Please post a (very) short snippet of your batch file (say the 10 first lines) and what you expect that to output.

Comment: input: :login @echo off color 0a cls set /p name=enter your name: set /p password=enter your password: if %password%==password goto page | :page cls echo MainMenu output: :login @echo off color 0a cls set /p name=enter your name: set /p password=enter your password: if %password%==passwordr goto page | :page cls echo Main Menu sorry you can't see the individual lines, I only want to see exactly what i've written to make that batchfile.

Answer (score 3):

I like adding this at the beginning of my batch scripts:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF /i {%1}=={ECHO} ECHO ON&SHIFT
```

This checks if the first argument is "ECHO" (case-insensitive). If it is, it turns ECHO ON, and then shifts the arguments such that %2 becomes %1, %3 becomes %2.
This way the script can behave as though you ran it normally, but with ECHO ON.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the below line from the batch file.

```
@echo off
```

Or make it on by doing

```
@echo on
```

Comment: output: C:\Users\accountname\Desktop> command + normal output. I would like to see just the command, not the location and thenormal output.

Comment: Sorry, you're not clear. What do you mean by "Now i want the batchfile to show the commands and text from the batchfile itself I've written."? Can you show a sample of what you are getting now and what you would want to see instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in a variable, then print it.

```
mycode = %Code Code Code%
echo %mycode%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this ain your batch file.

```
@type %0
```

Comment: Thanks, first I got some probles with the command but I found a way to settle it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding things but it seems like everyone is misunderstanding where the "@" symbol is necessary.  If you have this:

```
@echo off
```

Then you run commands like this:

```
@call mycommand.bat
```

But, if you have this at the top of your file:

```
echo off
```

Then, your commands are silenced like so:

```
call mycommand.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just open the command line and type this

```
type yourbatchfilename.bat >> code.txt
```

This would write your whole thing again in a txt file